# Modal Popup covering whole page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm beginner in BootStrap. I'm facing a problem in modal popup. Modal popup is covering whole screen when I open modal popup. I researched it and found a solution to change position from fixed to absolute, but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Here is the snippet of code i have used:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="myModal" style="background-color:white;" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            &times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            Sign In to ITRGuide</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post">
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ID="lblErrorMessage"></asp:Label></div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
                            <%--     <input name="txtEmail" type="text" runat="server" id="txtemail" class="form-control"
                                    onkeypress=" return onlyNumbersandSpecialChar()" placeholder="Email">--%>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" class="form-control" onkeypress=" return onlyNumbersandSpecialChar()"
                                placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Email is required"
                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
                            <%--  <input name="txtPassword" runat="server" type="password" id="txtpassword" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Password">--%>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ID="txtPwd" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Password is required"
                                ControlToValidate="txtPwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 22px; width: 200px;">
                            <cc2:CaptchaControl ID="cptCaptcha" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                                CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMinTimeout="5"
                                CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" FontColor="#529E00" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCaptcha" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Captcha is required"
                                ControlToValidate="txtCaptcha"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSignIn" class="btn-button btn-signin" Text="Sign In" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="fmyp text-center">
                            <a href="ForgotPassword.aspx" style="color: #4d8ff9;">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="canacc text-center">
                            New to ITRGuide? <a href="UserRegister.aspx" style="color: #4d8ff9;">Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code is not displaying. Just indent it 4 times and they will display. Anyway the good news is that it is working. Seeing no code is difficult to figure out. If it is image it could just be a case of adjusting the width and height

Comment: If i adjust the height and width then phone view is getting disturb...By default it should not cover the whole page, then why it is covering the  whole page i'm not able to figure out.